# sqlite - Foreign keys in VS2008 Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sqlite, designer

I'm starting over to use strong typed datasets in VS 2008 with sqlite and running into a problem. 
I have some tables that have foreign keys allready defined in the database. 
I can see those in the Server-Explorer. 
Now i create a new strong typed Dataset with the designer and add only one table from that realtion to the dataset. 
Then i like to add the second one and i get an error message "Unexpected error ... Source: Microsoft.VSDesigner; ErrorCode:-1" No Additional Info. 
The error does not occure if i add both tables at the same time (say i drag them from the serverexplorer).

Is there any way to add subsequent tables to an dataset that are in relation(s) to alreay added once?

Many thanks _rene

Comment: SQLite does not have strongly-typed datasets. I.E. you can insert text into an integer column, or vis-a-vis, and it won't care.

Comment: Of course you can have strongly typed datasets. However your comment is right, reguarding that you can add different datatypes to one column... But my problem is one totatly different. I do have a strongly typed dataset, where i dragged in one table. And when i try to drop the second table, which referencces the second one, i get that error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved .... Install SP1 for VS2008